# Dictionaries - print only part of values

Tags: python, dictionary

I only want the times that have nan beside them to be stored and printed, without the nan part. currently the output is this.

[image: output]

Id just like it so it prints 8:00, 15:00, 16:00, 17:00 for each day

my code is

```
free_times = {}
free_times.update(df3.drop_duplicates())

for key2 in free_times.values():
    print(key2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`free_times.values()` returns the values from the dictionary, not the keys. Use `.items()` to get both the keys and values, so you can check if it's `nan`.

```
from math import isnan

for key2, value2 in free_times.items():
    if isnan(value2):
        print(key2)
```

Comment: when i try this i get the following error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: Because you put a pandas series into the dictionary, not just the values from the series.

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary instead of just operating on the original dataframe?

Comment: because i need to compare those times with times in another dictionary

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295375/tell-users-when-there-is-an-event-on-during-their-breaks-in-college-python here is the full question if you need to understand what I am  trying to do

Comment: Maybe use `free_times = df3.drop_duplicates().to_dict()`. I'm not really a pandas expert.

Comment: alright thanks for your help